# How can I create a connection to any external database in Mosaic?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, database-connection, mosaic-decisions

We are using Mosaic to **load and read data from multiple sources like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle** in around 100 jobs using the reader node of Mosaic.

To configure this reader node to connect these databases, how to create a connection for each one of them? Are these connections globally available in Mosaic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mosaic Decisions supports a wide range of connectors.

You can create connections with different data assets by providing required connection details in the **Publish** tab under **Manager Persona**.

[image: Publish tab in Manager Persona]

**Publish** allows you to create a connection with any available source system by providing necessary detail like `IP, Port, username, password`, and other such required details to register/publish the metadata from the source system.

Here connections are of two types:

1. **Public**: This connection will be available to all. **No lock** symbol specifies that it is a **public** connection.
2. **Private**: This will **not be** available to all users. To use this connection you must provide your `username and password`. If the details are correct, only then the connection can be used. **A lock** symbol specifies that it is a **private** connection.

Once the **connection** is created, its **datasets** can be **published** and the same can be used for further processing in **Flows**.

**EDIT**

When you click on the `Publish` tab in `Manager persona`, you will see a list of available **connectors**. Refer screenshot below:

[image: available connectors in Manager persona]

Comment: Got it @V Ruvesh. What all RDBMS systems or cloud DB are supported to create connection?

Comment: @codeogeek you can go to Mosaic Manager and see the list of all the supported connectors under Publish tab.

Alternatively, you can refer the user manual provided by Mosaic Decisions to check out the different connector that are supported.

Link to user manual - https://mosaic.ga.lti-mosaic.com/usermanual/

Comment: @codeogeek I have added an edit with the screenshot showing all the available connectors you can configure